# Flex- building arrowhead for line

Tags: apache-flex, graphics

I wanted to check if there is a easy way to build an arrow for a line... currently I am trying to draw a triangle at end of the line- doable but a load of geometry to handle as the line could be at any angle and- anything build-in available?

Comment: There's nothing built in that will do this but I've previously gotten around that fact and the complex geometry by simply creating the arrow head as it's own sprite then setting the rotation angle (drawing the tip to the 0 point so rotation occurs about the tip) then using zRotation (using the arctan function and the x and y delta to get the angle).  If you'd like more detail on this method let me know and I'll write it up.

Comment: ok- I actually managed to get the triangle right, after some trial and error over last 45 minutes with the angle conventions... basically assumed angles equal at 60 degrees with one tip at line-end and calculated the 2 other points... works good!

Comment: It would be useful if you were to post the code that solved your problem as a solution to your question and marking it as the accepted answer. This will help others in the future who have the same issue. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var ahl:Number = 6;
myShape.graphics.beginFill(color); //had defined color earlier
myShape.graphics.moveTo(XTo, YTo);

// Point A is the end of line at (XTo, YTo).
// Points B and C are the two other points.
var Bx:Number = XTo - ahl * Math.sin(Math.PI/3 - angle);
var By:Number = YTo + ahl * Math.cos(Math.PI/3 - angle);

myShape.graphics.lineTo(Bx, By);

var Cx:Number=Bx-ahl*Math.cos(Math.PI/2 - angle);
var Cy:Number=By-ahl*Math.sin(Math.PI/2 - angle);

myShape.graphics.lineTo(Cx, Cy);
myShape.graphics.lineTo(XTo, YTo);
```

Answer (score 1):

Decided to do it anyhow just for the heck of it (Flex 3):

http://www.shaunhusain.com/TestArrowHeads/

Answer (score 0):

If you use Flex 4, the most flexible and easy way (in my opinion) would be to use 'Path' component (spark.primitives.Path).
FTQuest